# Covered effect don't work on ie7

Tags: jquery, background, internet-explorer-7, opacity

I created of social network buttons where there is a javascript function that create an effect of **light bulb slow ignition** that *covered the css hover*. It work, but on **IE7** no. The weird thing is that 'IE debug' don't report errors. You can see on this link http://www.matteowebdesigner.com/test/yesimove/

Code explanation:

```
<!-- html -->
<div class="social">
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/yesimove" class="facebook" rel="external">facebook</a>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/yesimove" class="twitter" rel="external">twitter</a>
    <a href="#" class="google" rel="external">google</a>
</div>
```

some Css for instant hover effect.

```
    #footer .social .facebook,
    #footer .social .facebook .fade {background-position:-80px -90px;}
    #footer .social .twitter,
    #footer .social .twitter .fade {background-position:-107px -90px;}
    #footer .social .google,
    #footer .social .google .fade{background-position:-134px -90px;}
    /*hover*/
    #footer .social .facebook:hover {background-position:-80px -117px;}
    #footer .social .twitter:hover {background-position:-107px -117px;}
    #footer .social .google:hover {background-position:-134px -117px;}
```

This code create two *span* on the *a* element for covered the background and the :hover css. Then in the second *span* it is hidden with the propriety *opacity:0* then with onmouseover opacity will became 1.

```
/*= socialOver =*/
function socialOver(){
    var socials = $('#footer .social a');
    $('<span class="fade"></span><span class="fade"></span>').appendTo(socials);
    socials.each(function(i,o){
        var bpx = $(o).css('backgroundPositionX');
        $(o).find('.fade:eq(1)').css({
            backgroundPosition:bpx+' -117px',
            opacity:0
        });
    });
    socials.find('.fade').on('mouseover',function(e){
        $(this).stop(true,true).animate({
            'opacity':'1'
        },300);
    }).on('mouseout',function(e){
        $(this).stop(true,true).animate({
            'opacity':'0'
        },600);
    });
};
```

Comment: I've found that adding <!DOCTYPE html> at the top of your page makes it much more likely that CSS will display correctly in IE.

Comment: Why are you animating the opacity yourself instead of using jQuery's `fadeIn` method?

Comment: But my doctype is identic, It is <!DOCTYPE html>.

Comment: You are right, I could use the function fadeIn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in ie7 is that the element inside the anchor element if they were set with the propriety position:absolute they aren't visible but if use the position:relative you caould see that javascritp code work. So for ie7 I used the ie7 hack ***:first-child+html** for create a different css only for ie7

```
/*Css*/
*:first-child+html #footer .social a .base {position:relative;top:-27px;cursor:pointer;} /*IE7 Hack*/
*:first-child+html #footer .social a .fade {position:relative;top:-54px;cursor:pointer;} /*IE7 Hack*/
```

Then I chaged the javascript, Now the code is creating a two element span.base and span.fade

```
/*= socialOver =*/
function socialOver(){
    var socials = $('#footer .social a');
    $('<span class="base"></span><span class="fade"></span>').appendTo(socials);
    socials.each(function(i,o){
        var bpx = $(o).css('backgroundPositionX');
        $(o).find('.fade').css({
            backgroundPosition:bpx+' -117px'
        }).fadeTo(0,0);
    });
    socials.find('.fade').hover(function(){
        $(this).stop().fadeTo(300,1);
    },function(){
        $(this).stop().fadeTo(600,0);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

IE<=8 doesn't understand the opacity attribute, it uses filters, you should use jquery's fadeTo method that will take care of all browsers

```
socials.find('.fade').hover(function(){
    $(this).stop().fadeTo(300,1);
  }), function(){
    $(this).stop().fadeTo(600,0);
  }
);
```

edited: using hover instead of mouseover and mouseout

Comment: I changed the opacity with fadeTo but the result does not change.
http://jsfiddle.net/MatteoWebDesigner/LqXzt/

Comment: are the mouseover and mouseout event triggering? use IE debugger to check that, maybe that's another problem, jquery have this hover(function,function) method to bind a mousehover effect, i'll update my answer

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that there was an event hover, I left mousover and mouseout. Now I am changing the code and I am seeing that the code on the IE7, It create the element *span* but It dosen't do the fadeIn. maybe It is a Css problem, I think this because the IE dubug dosen't find errors.

http://jsfiddle.net/MatteoWebDesigner/LqXzt/
http://www.matteowebdesigner.com/test/yesimove/

Comment: I was as thought, It's css problem because I changed the rule 'position:absolute' on the span elements and I could to see all three element and the fadein worked it.